# invoking web-service from servlet causes ClassCastException

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, jax-ws

I've created JBoss login module and it is working perfectly fine. Sample below:

```
public class UserLoginModule extends UsernamePasswordLoginModule {
   private static UserService userService;

   @Override
   public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler,
                      Map<String, ?> sharedState, Map<String, ?> options) {
   super.initialize(subject, callbackHandler, sharedState, options);
   String wsdlUrl = (String) options.get("wsdlURL");
   UserService.initialize(wsdlUrl);
   userService = new UserService();
}

@Override
protected boolean validatePassword(String inputPassword, 
                                  String expectedPassword) {
    boolean result = false;

    try {
       String response =
       userService.getUserPort().checkOperator(getUsername(), inputPassword);

       if(RESULT_OK.equals(response)) {
          result = true;
       } else {
             result = false;
       }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        log.error("Error when invoking UserService!", e);
    }
        return result;
   }
}
```

This module is deployed in common/lib directory in JBoss. Everything is fine when system tries to authenticate the user and invokes the validatePassword method.

Now, when I'm trying to invoke UserService from the servlet, which is in web application (the same which uses custom login module) the exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.<clinit>(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:533)
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:107)
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
    $Proxy173.unblockOperator(Unknown Source)
    pl.servlet.UserServlet.doPost(UserServlet.java:93)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

The servlet looks as follows:

```
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserServlet.class.getName());
    private static UserService userService;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        userService = new UserService();
    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
    throws  ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        String result = null;
        String login = req.getParameter("login");
        result = userService.getUserPort().unblockOperator(login);
    }
}
```

I'm using JBoss 5.1 EAP.
Any ideas how to fix that? WEB-INF directory of my web application (the one containing servlet) is empty - no jars there.

Comment: WEB-INF/lib is empty. Only standard jars from JBoss. It worked when invoking web service from Login Module directly. While invoking from servlet there is a problem...

Comment: On the surface, it appears you may have `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl` and/or `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.api.JAXBRIContext` being loaded by two (or more) different ClassLoaders.

Comment: Yep. The problem, as you can see from the stacktrace (SOAPFaultBuilder creation) occurs only when there is an exception on the other side (web-service implementation). When the service does not throw any exceptions there are also no exceptions on the side invoking the service and everything is working fine...

Answer (score 3):

you can try setting the system property

**javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext=com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactor**

This will pick up the default contextfactory provided by jre